# Display class name with parents function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am using .parents() function of **`jQuery`** behind a button.
I want to display the class name to check.
For e.g i am using:

```
row = (this).parents();
alert(row);
```

but class name is not displayed and it display **"object object"**.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve an array of all class name of `parents` using this:

```
var parentCls = $(this).parents().map(function () {
                    return this.className;
                }).get().join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(this).parent().attr("class");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `row` represents the parent element.

So to retrieve its class you have to do like this:

```
alert($(row).attr("class"));
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$(row).attr("class")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 alert($(this).parent().attr("class"););
```